# MySQL and PHP: Unkown Column in WHERE clause, but columns do exist

Tags: php, mysql

I have read through so many posts on this subject my head is ready to explode.

I am trying to create a little form that will update a database of prospective customers for a client, as well as list out all of the entries in the database. I am not a backend developer which I have mentioned to my client repeatedly, but my client doesn't seem to care... So I'm trying to work this out on the fly.

I have created all of the following columns in the table "prospects": "id", "fname", "lname", "tickler", and "info". So I know that they are there. Also, they are working just fine for the list of prospects I have below the update form (which works just fine).

But when I try to update the database, I get a "Could not update data: Unknown column '$id' in 'where clause'" error. If I remove the WHERE clause, it switches to "Could not update data: Unknown column '$fname' in 'field list'". At the moment I'm just trying to get it to work with the First Name using the ID # as the condition. Eventually it will be able ot update the other fields, too.

I don't know if anyone can see the page (I think my client password protected the page and I'm still logged in), but you can try viewing it at http://www.vlist.info.

Here is the code:

```
<body>

<h2>Update Prospect</h2>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'dbo558532591';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbname = 'db558532591';
$tablename = 'prospects';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];
$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];
$tickler = $_POST['tickler'];
$info = $_POST['info'];

mysql_select_db( $dbname ) or die('Could not find table:' . mysql_error());

$sql = 'UPDATE prospects SET fname = $fname WHERE id = $id';

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID:</th>
            <th>First Name:</th>
            <th>Last Name:</th>
            <th>Tickler:</th>
            <th>Info:</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="id" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lname" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="tickler" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="info" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>

<h2>Prospects</h2>

<?php $localhost="host";$username="dbo558532591";$password="pass";$database="db558532591";
mysql_connect($localhost,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database.");
$query="SELECT * FROM prospects";$result=mysql_query($query);
$num=mysql_numrows($result);mysql_close();?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Tickler</th>
        <th>Info</th>
    </tr>
    <?php $i=0;while ($i < $num) {
        $id=mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
        $fname=mysql_result($result,$i,"fname");
        $lname=mysql_result($result,$i,"lname");
        $tickler=mysql_result($result,$i,"tickler");
        $info=mysql_result($result,$i,"info");
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lname; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $tickler; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $info; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php $i++;}?>
```

Comment: Can you check my answer and explanation

Comment: Use prepared statements, more secure, less errors

Comment: @AndréDaniel: downvotes are for indicating that a question does not feature research or is unclear (see the hover text on the link). Now, you _may_ technically downvote for any reason at all, but I don't think it is within the spirit of this site. I am thus upvoting.

Comment: Dan is correct - this code contains SQL injection vulnerabilities, and thus should not be put live until it is made safe.

Comment: @halfer as you want, but personally I think using deprecated functions in what appears to be new code is already a lack of research effort.

Comment: @André, an interesting perspective, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$sql = 'UPDATE prospects SET fname = "'.$fname.'" WHERE id = '.$id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with the way you construct queries

```
$sql = 'UPDATE prospects SET fname = $fname WHERE id = $id';
echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
 UPDATE prospects SET fname = $fname WHERE id = $id // Your variables are not recognized and not read
```

Solution :

Change your query to

```
$sql = "UPDATE prospects SET `fname` = '$fname' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
```

**Always put queries inside double quotes. Encapsulate column names with backticks and variables with single quote**

**For more understanding about single and double quote usages**

*Single quotes does not look for variables while double quote does*

**Case 1 :**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value';
    echo $sql;
```

output is

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value
```

Here if you see single quote does not look for a variable within it. Whatever there is inside single quotes, it is considered as a string and returned as such.

**Case 2:**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = $value";
    echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
 SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = 10
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as int.

**Case 3:**

```
    $value = 10;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = '$value'";
    echo $sql;
```

Output is

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE `column_name` = '10'
```

Here Since the query is inside double quotes, That variable is read. but considered as string as it is encapsulated with single quotes.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but it replicates the SQL injection vulnerabilities in the original post. "Fixing" the problem this way will just get the site hacked.

Answer (score 0):

In your $sql string you are passing the literals "$fname" and "$id" into the query, rather than getting the values of the variables.

In addition to Corentin's solution you could also try this:

```
$sql = sprintf('UPDATE prospects SET fname = "%s" WHERE id = %d', $fname, $id);
```

Comment: Strings should be wrapped with quotes Right?

Comment: You are correct. I've put the quotes around the delimiter to be replaced by the $fname variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be fixed to remove SQL injection vulnerabilities. You can do so thus:

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['id']);
```

Do that on all cases of reading from `$_GET`, `$_REQUEST` and `$_POST`.

Bear in mind that the library you are using is deprecated, and you should switch to either mysqli or PDO/mysql. Both offer *parameterisation*, which is the preferred way of injecting user-input into queries safely.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to add on to @IndraKumarS's answer, you should **always** use `mysqli_*` or PDO statements.

```
$sql = "UPDATE `prospects` SET `fname` = '$fname' WHERE `id` = '$id'";
mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
```

The mysqli_* function is much more secure

**Backticks**

You should use backticks on table and column names. It's safer and if you have a table name that happens to be a mysql operator it will stop the query from working.

**Double Quotes**

For the query string, double quotes will allow $variables to be expanded as their values. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

As a side note, you should always enclose $variables in 'single quotes' to make sure your query string works correctly.